# Use shared library(.so) in spring web application deployed on glassfish web server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-native-interface, glassfish

I am using System.loadLib() in a spring web  application deployed on glassfish to load a .so (jni shared library) in my application...But when System.loadLibrary executes the server stop suddenly without any exception in server log!

what is the problem ? 
my code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/getdata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class temperatureController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/temp" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
     float getTemperature(){
    System.err.print("beforeeeeeeeeeeeN");
        NativeClass n = new NativeClass();
        System.err.print("beforeeeeeeeeeeeLoadLib");
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("NativeClass");
            System.err.print("LoadedintempClass");
        }
        catch (Throwable e){
            System.err.print("not loaded in temp class");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.err.print("afteeeeeeeerLoadLib");
            float temp =  n.getTemperature(); // invoke the native method
        System.err.print("tttttttttt");
        System.err.print(temp);
           return temp ;
     }
```

server log :

```
 [2016-05-30T19:40:36.364+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1464637236364] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      beforeeeeeeeeeeeN]]

    [2016-05-30T19:40:36.391+0000] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1464637236391] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      beforeeeeeeeeeeeLoadLib]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably a segmentation fault caused by the library and it brings down whole JVM. Try running GlasssFish from command line using `bin/asadmin start-domain --verbose` to keep running in the same console window. You may be able to see `SEGMENTATION FAULT` in the console if it's the case.